# Adobe Facebook API calling "/me/picture" fails

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook

I'm using the [official Adobe Facebook API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html) in my Flash/AS3 application and for some reason the call the `/me/picture` seems to fail whereas the the call the `/me/friends` seems to work just fine:

This works OK:

```
Facebook.api('/me/friends', onFriendsLoaded );

protected function onFriendsLoaded( response:Object, fail:Object ) : void
{
   // I can get the friends from the response object
}
```

This fails:

```
Facebook.api('/me/picture', onPictureLoaded );

protected function onPictureLoaded( response:Object, fail:Object ) : void
{
   // Here response is null and fail is ÿØÿà
}
```

I'm calling both methods right after each other. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /me/picture call is actually not an api call at all. http://graph.facebook.com/me/picture is the url of the photo. You can actually set an image to that url. I am not an expert in Flash, but if you were doing this in html you would do the following:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/facebook_id/picture" />
```

This would show the users picture. Additionally, if you wanted to download the picture's bytes you would just make a normal web request. The response stream would be the image file.

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense actually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
function onPictureLoaded(response:Object,fail:Object):void{

if (fail)
 {
 trace("Error");
 } 
 var friends = response as Array;
 var l:int = friends.length;
 for (var i:int=0; i < l; i++)
 {
 trace("http://graph.facebook.com/" + friends[i].id + "/picture/")
 }
}
```